# Images from "i.stack.imgur.com" uploading but not displaying

Tags: support, images

Seems the images can be uploaded to "i.stack.imgur.com" but not displaying in GIS Stack-Exchange.

Is there anyone else experiencing this issue or related issues with images in GIS SE?

> [it might be an over zealous change at our Work/IT/firewall]

I have checked the last 20 new questions on GIS-SE and no images are in any of the posts..

Comment: (1) I have no such issues. (2) An issue like this is unlikely to affect just GIS--it would affect all of SE--and therefore should be raised on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) instead of here.